# preg_replace between [{ and }]

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this string :

```
$string='My String [{Text_001}] My String [{Text_002}] ';
```

I would like to replace with preg_replace [{something}] by $something (ex : [{Text_001}] -> $Text_001).

I have an error in my preg_replace :

```
$string = preg_replace('/([{.+?)+(}])/i', "$1", $string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('~\[\{(.+?)\}\]~', "\$$1", $string);
# My String $Text_001 My String $Text_002
```

[Explanation example](http://regex101.com/r/mJ5sR6).

Answer (score 0):

[`\[` and `{` have a special meaning in PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) (plus you had malformed regexp). Just escape them:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\\[\\{(.+?)\\}\\])/i', "$1", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php
$string='My String [{Text_001}] My String [{Text_002}] ';

$string = preg_replace("~".preg_quote('[{')."(.*?)".preg_quote('}]')."~","something", $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

Output after replacing `[{something}]` by `something`:

```
My String something My String something
```